Как верно переносить строчки для txt в php
Необходимо из базы данных, сформировать список для txt
echo ['Disallow', 'Allow'][$r['type']].': *'.$r['url']."\r\n";

Слышал что в некоторых случаях это не работает, именно подобного рода переноса строки.
Что скажите, есть ли понадежней вариант?

echo ['Disallow', 'Allow'][$r['type']].': *'.$r['url'].PHP_EOL;
